# Meaning of "kick him off his feet"

Tags: expressions

Can anyone help me find the meaning of the sentence "kick him off his feet"? This is the context of it...

> Send him to school.
>   Force him to crawl.
>   Teach him how to cheat.
>   Kick him off his feet.

Comment: It looks like it was intended to be a more aggressive version of *sweep him off his feet*

Comment: You seem to have left out half the lyrics of the song. Why?

Comment: @oerkelens: Well, one logical reason would be to reduce biases.

Comment: @VatsalManot: removing context when looking for meaning is hardly logical and seldomly productive.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have left out half the lyrics of the song. Why?
You have quoted song lyrics, it would be nice to tell us that at least (and credit the author!)

Seeing the title of this song (**Systematic Death**) and the [full lyrics from plyrics.com](http://www.plyrics.com/lyrics/crass/systematicdeath.html), I dare to doubt that it means something as sweet as "sweep him of his feet":

> System, system, system.
>   Send him to school.
>   System, system, system.
>   Force him to crawl.
>   System, system, system.
>   Teach him how to cheat.
>   System, system, system.
>   Kick him off his feet.

"The system" is described in the song as bringing up kids to maturity, to use and abuse them afterwards.

So I'd suggest reading "kick him off his feet" as quite literally applying abrupt force to the poor kid with a foot (kicking him) in such a way that he will fall over (off his feet).

Comment: Thanks! I´m trying to translate it to portuguese and it wasn´t clear the meaning of it. I guess now i can look for an expression that can more or less give the same meaning to the sentence.